# Angular Hidden Ignores

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use the Hidden property in Angular2 and when I include a style that alters the display of the DIV, the hidden property is ignored.

When the code below is run, both divs are displayed.
When I remove the class .displayInline the first DIV is hidden and the second is displayed (as expected).

Can I use Hidden and the display CSS together?

```
import {ComponentAnnotation as Component, ViewAnnotation as View, bootstrap, NgIf} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello'
})
@View({
    template: `<style>.displayInline{ display:inline }</style><span *ng-if="name">Hello, {{name}}!</span>
    <div>
                <div [hidden]="hideDiv1()" class="displayInline">should be hidden.</div>
                <div [hidden]="hideDiv2()" class="displayInline">should be displayed.</div>
    </div>`,
    directives: [NgIf]
})
export class Hello {
    name: string = 'World';
    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.name = 'NEW World'
        }, 2000);
    }

    hideDiv1(){
        return true;
    }   

    hideDiv2(){
        return false;
    }
}

bootstrap(Hello);
```

Repository:https://github.com/albi000/ng2-play

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35578093/873282

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note: `<span>`'s default to "display: inline", you may want to use them instead.

Currently classes override [hidden]. I agree, this isn't as effective as ng-hide/ng-show and I hope it is fixed in future versions of angular2. It is currently [an open on issue on the Angular2 repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/506).

You can overcome the problem by simply wrapping your [hidden] element with the class.

```
<span class="someClass">
  <span [hidden]="hideDiv1()">should be hidden.</span>
</span>
```

Comment: The referenced issue has been closed, and I suspect it has been rolled up with some `aria-hidden` work. I have asked for clarification. See [differences](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/).

Comment: It works but If we write `span` tag inside a `tr` of a `table` it breaks the table row. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 33):

I faced similar problem with btn class of bootstrap

```
<button [hidden]="!visible" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
```

I solved this by adding

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

at the end of css stylesheet I use globally. 
This is solved the problem for now.

Comment: This is good but, relies on specificity. In my case it didn't work because it got overriden.

Comment: you can use `display: none !important;`  still

Answer (score 12):

You can use `style.display` instead of `hidden` if you need more fine-grained control over visibility.

```
<div [style.display]="active?'inherit':'none'"></div>
```

Comment: This one is great to efficiently replace *ngIf="active"  when the div have a nested component which need to be bootstraped