# Hide-show buttons

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 buttons in my template (`tbody`):

```
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.servicelist">
       <td colspan="3"> {{ service_rec.name }} </td>
       <td align="center" valign="middle">

         // 1 - button
         <button [style.background-color]="service_rec.status == 
           'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'" 
            class="btn btn-default">
            {{ service_rec.status }}
         </button>
        </td>
        <td align="center">

             // 2 - button
            <button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled"
               [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 
               'true' ? 'green' : 'orange'"
                class="btn btn-warning" 
               (click)="onPost(service_rec.title, 
               service_rec.status, service_rec.id)">
               {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | stopPipe }}
            </button>

            // 3 - button
            <button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled"
               [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 
               'true' ? 'green' : 'orange'"
                class="btn btn-warning" 
               (click)="onStartPost(service_rec.title, 
                service_rec.status, service_rec.id)">
                {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | startPipe }}
             </button>
         </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

And now i would show/hide 3 - button, when:

1 - button: Online -> then show 2 button - Stop (`stopPipe`) - and hide 3 - button

And if:

1 - button: Offline -> then show 3 button - Start (`startPipe`) - and hide 2 - button

How do this? with ngShow? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `<template>` tag right ?

```
<td align="center">
    <template *ngIf="service_rec.status=='Online'">
         // 2 - button
        <button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled"
           [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 
           'true' ? 'green' : 'orange'"
            class="btn btn-warning" 
           (click)="onPost(service_rec.title, 
           service_rec.status, service_rec.id)">
           {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | stopPipe }}
        </button>
    </template>

    <template *ngIf="service_rec.status=='Offline'">

        // 3 - button
        <button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled"
           [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 
           'true' ? 'green' : 'orange'"
            class="btn btn-warning" 
           (click)="onStartPost(service_rec.title, 
            service_rec.status, service_rec.id)">
            {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | startPipe }}
         </button>
    </template>
</td>
```

Comment: ill do this, add `<template>` tag into my buttons, and now, all buttons are erase

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good trick written in this answer: [What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular2)

Also you can toggle a class with `display: none;` using [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)