# Hide compoments in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I wanted to hide the components so that when he had another and when he returned was exactly as it was the only problem is that I do not know how I can do it anyone have any examples or know of something similar for me to realize how it's done ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<my-comp [hidden]="isHidden">
```

See also [What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular2/35578093#35578093)