# Angular ng-show="false" is not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

First of all, I have searched already for this topic. There are lots of questions of answers for this, but none address my issue. So please, be kind and ***don't*** mark this question as duplicate.

I am trying to display and hide an *ion-item* on my hybrid application. The tests I am doing are done solely on the html side.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="secondary">
        <ion-title>
            CEPs!
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content margin>
    <ion-item ng-show="false">{{ item.cep + "\n" + item.logradouro + "\n" + item.complemento + "\n" + item.bairro + "\n" + item.localidade + "\n" +
        item.uf}}
    </ion-item>

    <form margin-top (ngSubmit)="test()">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="number" max="99999999" [(ngModel)]="form.cep" name="form"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <button ion-button type="submit" center>Pesquisar CEP</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

I set ion-item ng-show as "false", which on editors like the one at W3Schools works correctly. But here it is not working at all. What should I do?

My versions:
Ionic: 3.5.0
Cordova: 7.0.1
Angular: 1.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [hidden] intead of ng-show

```
<ion-item [hidden]="false">
```

check [hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35578093/5826733)

Comment: Wow that made it! Why doesn't ng-show work here? Do you know?

Comment: @Ortiz because `ng-show` is related to angular v 1.xx that is not working any more with angular v 2.x or higher this is the alternative.

Comment: @Ortiz perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf`.

```
<ion-item *ngIf="false">
```

Or you can use `hidden` as @abd Elrahman Telb answered.

```
<ion-item [hidden]="false">
```

The difference is `*ngIf` completely removes content from DOM if the condition meets false. Where as `[hidden]` (you observe the [] which means one way binding of angular to the property) means hidden attribute will be added if condition meets true which is html property.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is an old post, but the platform I'm working on is still primarily running AngularJS V1 and I'm adding this just in case someone else stumbles across it.*

I had a variable assignment based on a conditional check and although the variable was evaluating to false, ngShow continued to display the element. So, since the ngShow/ngHide directives are evaluated as `truthy/falsy`, switching to strict interpretation fixed my issue :D.

Ex:

**Not Working:** `<ng-show="varIsFalse">`   **Working:**   `<ng-show="varIsFalse === true">`