# What's the advantage of using [hidden] over *ngIf when ngIf seems superior due to the DOM ligthening?

Tags: angular

Is there any advantage of using `[hidden]` over the `*ngIf`?
ngIf takes the entire div off of the DOM tree so it lightens up the JS code base, whereas hidden just sweeps stuff under the carpet.

In this case, a question arises; whether or not, there is any advantage of choosing `[hidden]` over *`ngIf`?

```
<div *ngIf="expression">{{val}}</div>

<div [hidden]="!expression">{{val}}</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular2)

Comment: Did you spend 5 minutes researching before you posted this question?

Comment: Tim, most of the docs and answers on this only covers the difference. As a matter of fact, I did mention what the diff is while constructing the question. To answer your point which I do find value in general, please note that it would take more time to figure out the insight that I'm after. And when one is very tight on time and deadlines, one does not always have the luxury of doing that research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, it depends on your needs.  We can give more helpful advice if you fine tune your question with your specific use-case.

`[hidden]` will use CSS to hide the element (it's always there), whereas `*ngIf` will add or remove the element from the DOM.

It's generally expensive to add and remove stuff from the DOM, but if you're doing it all of once or twice, it does not matter.  I have found in my projects that which to use is generally dictated by the logic of the situation.

Comment: So, if you are going to be switching a div section on the page back and forth, it makes more sense then, to go with the [hidden]. That's because in this case, choosing the &ngIf path ( which removes all that div out of the DOM )  would go against you - in terms of performance. This is an interesting insight! Cause DOM-ligthening was the very feature that sells the *ngIf.

Answer (score 2):

**`*ngIf`** will remove elements from DOM.

**`[hidden]`** does not remove the elements from DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements .

Even though the differences are not much , first way that are not in the DOM have less performance impact  appear to be faster when using **`*ngIf`** compared to **`[hidden]`**

Comment: could you please re-phrase the last sentence?