# Show Hide a div in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, ng-show

**I am trying to show/hide a div in angular 7 using ng-model and ng-hide but its not working.**

`button` to Show/Hide- used `ng-model` to set expression

```
    <button type="checkbox" ng-model="show" >show/hide</button>
```

`div` to Show/Hide,  Used `ng-hide` to hide the `div`

```
<div class="row container-fluid" ng-hide="show" id="divshow" >
  Div Content
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried `ng-model` and `ng-hide` still it's not working.
Please provide a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 22):

In your HTML

```
<button (click)="toggleShow()" type="checkbox" >show/hide</button>

<div *ngIf="isShown" class="row container-fluid"  id="divshow" >
Div Content

</div>
```

in your component class add this:

```
isShown: boolean = false ; // hidden by default


toggleShow() {

this.isShown = ! this.isShown;

}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this solution:

Solution 1:

```
<div *ngIf="show" class="row container-fluid"  id="divshow" >
        Div Content
    </div>
```

Solution 2:

```
<div [hidden]="!show" class="row container-fluid"  id="divshow" >
            Div Content
        </div>
```

Comment: There is a big difference between the two. ngIf removes and creates the element. [hidden] no.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `<div *ngIf="show"`

and use in your .ts file a boolean that you can change the value if the button is tiggered

Answer (score 3):

You can use `change` event handler if you are using `type='checkbox'`

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="show = !show" ng-model="show" />
Div to Show/Hide

<div class="row container-fluid" *ngIf="show" id="divshow" >
Div Content
</div>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-example-tszyxe?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I can ask you a question concerning your code?

Answer (score 1):

**Best Possible Way :**

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="show = !show" ng-model="show"/>
show/hide

<div class="row container-fluid" [hidden]="!show" id="divshow" >
Div Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat way to hide/remove items, specially handy if there is a list of items.

Note how it takes advantage of [Angular's template variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) (#ListItem).

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
  <div #ListItem>
    <button (click)="close(ListItem)">
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

```js
  close(e: HTMLElement) {
    e.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use a flag In your ts file, By default flag false

```
<button type="checkbox" (click)="flag= !flag">{{falg=== true ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}</button>
```