# How can I hide an element (within a component) depending on the current component? (I'm using router)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am basically able to completely hide a component, but I do not know how I can hide or show an element of a component.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  headerFooterVisible: boolean;
  constructor(private router: Router){
    router.events.subscribe(e => {
    if(e instanceof NavigationEnd){
      if(e.urlAfterRedirects != '/'){
        this.headerFooterVisible= true;
      }else{
        this.headerFooterVisible= false;
      }

    }
  });
  }
  name = 'Angular 4';
  private activatedComponent;
  onActivate(component){
    this.activatedComponent = component;
  }


<menu *ngIf="headerFooterVisible"></menu>
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
<footer *ngIf="headerFooterVisible"></footer>
```

I want the variable `{{headerFooterVisible}}` to be shown in each of my components in real time. how can I do it?

this is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6ffqn?file=app/another.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can create service using `BehavoirSubject` which it will store the value from `headerFooterVisible`. In componenets where you want to access to `headerFooterVisible` you can subscribe this service in ts and get value or use `async pipe` in html.

For example - CacheService:

```
export class CacheService {

  readonly headerFooterVisible$: Observable<boolean>;
  private headerFooterVisibleSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false); // this place you can set first value, you can choose true or false

  constructor() {
    this.headerFooterVisible$ = this.headerFooterVisibleSubject.asObservable();
  }

  addNewValueToSubject(value: boolean) {
      this.headerFooterVisibleSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

In components you have to inject this service.

```
constructor(private cacheService: CacheService) {}
```

When you want to get value:

```
this.cacheService.headerFooterVisible$.subscrive((value: boolean) => console.log(boolean);
```

and add new value:

```
this.cacheService.addNewValueToSubject(this.headerFooterVisible);
```

You remember about takeUntil.

Comment: can you help me with this demo please? It is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you can just use

```
[hidden]="headerFooterVisible"
```

For more about hidden: **[What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular 2+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular-2)**