# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I am getting the following error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.

This occurs when I try to add a div with an ngIf and inside a google map:

HTML:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Location by map?</label>
                <mat-select formControlName="ubication" [(ngModel)]="mapVisibility" class="form-control" placeholder="Select option">
                    <mat-option disabled>Select option</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="visible">Yes</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="hidden">No</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="mapVisibility === 'visible'">
                <div class="example-form">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <input matInput type="text" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" #agmSearch placeholder="Enter address">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>

                <agm-map id="googleMap" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
                    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [markerDraggable]="true" (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)"></agm-marker>
                </agm-map>
            </div>
```

TS:

```
mapVisibility: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getPlacesAutocomplete();
}

getPlacesAutocomplete() {
// load Places Autocomplete
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
this.setCurrentLocation();
this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
  types: ['address']
});
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
  // get the place result
  let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

  // verify result
  if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
    return;
  }

  // set latitude, longitude and zoom
  this.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
  this.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
  this.zoom = 12;
  });
 });
});
}

private setCurrentLocation() {
if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    this.zoom = 15;
    this.getAddress(this.lat, this.lng);
  });
}
}

  getAddress(latitude, longitude) {
this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
this.geoCoder.geocode({ 'location': { lat: latitude, lng: longitude } }, (results, status) => {
  console.log(results);
  if (status === 'OK') {
    if (results[0]) {
      this.zoom = 12;
      this.address = results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
    } else {
      window.alert('No results found');
    }
  } else {
    window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
  }
});
}
```

I extracted the code from here: [Angular 8/7 | Add Google Maps with Location Search in Angular 2 plus Applications using Angular Google Maps Module (@agm/core) Easily](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-google-maps-in-angular-2-plus-applications-using-angular-google-maps-module-agm-core-easily/)

ERROR:
[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwr3l.png)

Although I get this error, the map works fine, but I cannot implement the search for places by entering an address in an input, which does work if I remove the div that contains the ngIf. what is this about?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit

```
ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.getPlacesAutocomplete();
}
```

> View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

you need the change the `*ngIf` to `hidden` this way the elemnt will be avilable otherwise the `searchElementRef` will be null until the condition is true

```html
<div [hidden]="mapVisibility === 'visible'">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @malbarmawi ! implement ngAfterViewInit but it also doesn't work and shows the same error..

Comment: The other problem is this `*ngIf="mapVisibility === 'visible'"` when this will be true

Comment: What alternative do you propose?

Comment: you can just hide the elment *ngIf remove it  try this `[ngStyle]={display : mapVisibility !== 'visible' ? 'none' : 'initial ' }`

Comment: or you can use `hidden`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular-2

Comment: @AguFortini I have update the answer , and check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-hidden

Comment: It worked as implemented in the link [hidden] . It was not necessary to add the ngAfterViewInit, only with the OnInit it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Call your function after the Component is initialized (DOM Loaded) on `ngAfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getPlacesAutocomplete();
}
```

Or surround your code on setTimeout (Bad idea) :

```
ngOnInit() {

setTimeout( _ =>   this.getPlacesAutocomplete() , 1000)

}
```

if you are using `ngAfterViewInit` don't forget `class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit`

Comment: but in both case the searchElementRef  will be null untill the condtion is true , check the template   `<div *ngIf="mapVisibility === 'visible'">` 

Comment: I think if he use hidden will solve the problem , I have already tested 