# How to hide a dynamic div using its id in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 div,I need hide and show it based on dropdown selection.When my selected option is chartdata 'ChartData' div will show again when I select tabledata 'TableData' div will show. I can easily do it with ngif,but the problem is 'TableData' div is generating  from plugin,I cannot put there ngif tag so I need to use its id only.Is there any way to do it with angular 7.
Here is the code.

### home.component.html

```
<select (change)="onChangeEvent($event)"><option>Chartdata</option><option>Tabledata</option></select>
<div id="chart">ChartData</div>
<div id="table">TableData</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 

    nestedjson:any;
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {


     }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.nestedjson = [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}];

} 

onChangeEvent(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.value); // should print option1
}   


}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should do it with `*ngIf` condition, and As you said some part is dynamic so in that case you should re-initilize third party plugin on every time user changes/selected another option. like below -

```
<select (change)="onChangeEvent($event)"><option>Chartdata</option><option>Tabledata</option></select>
<div *ngIf='selectedOption === "chartData"' id="chart">ChartData</div>
<div *ngIf='selectedOption === "tableData"' id="table">TableData</div>


onChangeEvent() { */Re initilize third party plugin/*}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have access to this div itself <div *ngIf='selectedOption === "tableData"' id="table">TableData</div>I cannot put any tag there,that is coming from plugin, thats why is there any solution we can use it's id like jquery to hide it

Comment: So in that you should wrap your third party plugin template somewhere in the another wrapper say another `div` and put condition on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the [hidden] property

```
[hidden]="!isChartSelected"
[hidden]="!isTableSelected"
```

Bear in mind that this only hides the div and it does not remove it from the dome.

A safer and backwards compatible (less than i.e. 11) option, would be to go with a class and use ngClass to show hide.

```
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And then

```
[ngClass]="{'hidden': selectedValue === 'Chart'}"
[ngClass]="{'hidden': selectedValue === 'Table'}"
```

If you can't use ngClass, then you can go with plain old javascript like this:

```
let targetElement = document.getElementsById('chart');
targetElement.classList.remove("hidden");   //remove the class
let targetElement = document.getElementsById('table');
targetElement.classList.add("hidden");   //add the class
```

And vise-versa if you want to hide the one and show the other.

For more information on the matter you can check this wonderfull explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular-2)

Comment: thanks but I don't have access to this div <div id="table">TableData</div>, I cannot put any tags in the html dom .It is  generating  from plugin

Comment: Ok, check the alternative solution with plain old javascript that I added to the answer.