# Angular 9 ng-if and ng-show - element is always displayed

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-show

In Angular 9 I have code in that I want to hide html element. In typescript I have public property:

```
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public postModel: any = {};
```

And in Html component I want to check if I should display html element:

```
<mat-video ng-if="postModel.moviePath != ''" src="{{ postModel.moviePath }}"></mat-video>
```

But element `mat-video` is always displayed.
When I wanted to use ng-show the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using angularjs syntax, with angular it should be [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive

```
<mat-video *ngIf="postModel.moviePath != ''" src="{{ postModel.moviePath }}"></mat-video>
```

Also there is **`NO`** ng-show with angular.

Comment: also a note for OP, there is no angular version of angularJS's `ng-show` or `ng-hide`

Comment: so how to hide element in Angular 9?

Comment: you can do like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular-2